# Flexible number of arguments to haskell program

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching, command-line-arguments, io-monad

I am using the `System.FilePath.Find` module of filemanip to recursively find all files I need to process (here I will be using just printing to console as the action to perform, in order not confuse things). Now, this code:

```
import System.Environment (getArgs)
import System.FilePath (FilePath)
import System.Directory (doesDirectoryExist, getDirectoryContents,doesFileExist)
import Control.Monad
import System.FilePath.Find (find,always,fileType,(==?),FileType(..),(&&?),extension)


main= do 
    [dbFile,input]<- getArgs
    files <- findFiles input
    mapM_ putStrLn files 
    return ()

searchExtension :: String
searchExtension = ".hs"

findFiles :: FilePath -> IO [String]
findFiles = find (always) ( fileType ==? RegularFile &&? extension ==? searchExtension)
```

works well with this call

> ./myprog tet .

In this case, the `get` argument is ignored (will be the output database file later) and the second argument is searched recursively for matching files. It also allows me to specify just a single file, which is just perfect!

BUT, I would like to be able to specify

> ./myprog tet path1 path2 path4 file1

but this of course fails in the pattern matching:

> ./myprog tet . .
>
> myprogt: user error (Pattern match failure in do expression at myprog.hs:11:9-22)

Now, how do I make this program more flexible, so that I can take more than two arguments?

Sorry for asking this, actually, but my Haskell knowledge is limited but increasing for every new thing I have to do in my first project.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, you can use a different pattern like:

```
(dbFile:inputs) <- getArgs
```

where `dbFile` will match the first argument passed while `inputs` will match any number of file names (even `0`. If you want at least one path name use `inputs@(_:_)` instead of the simple `inputs`).

Then you can use `mapM` to call `findFiles` for each path in `inputs`:

```
files <- mapM findFiles input
mapM_ putStrLn $ concat files
```

Instead of `mapM` you could modify `findFiles` to accept a `[FilePath]` argument instead of a simple `FilePath`.

---

Note that to parse command arguments you could consider using some module like [`getopt`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/System-Console-GetOpt.html). You should also read [this](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/GetOpt) page about argument handling.